# If my gemfile specifies a rails version, what is the purpose of installing rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

I am being told to enhance an existing project running ruby.  Coming from the Java world the package managers in Ruby/Rails are a bit confusing.

If I have a Gemfile that seem to be similar to having pom.xml with Java/Maven.  If the project I have been told to work on has

> gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

Does this mean rails will be automatically installed?  Do I still need to use RVM to install Ruby itself separately?  I'm told on [this tutorial](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html) that I can install Ruby and Rails for a specific project only by calling.  If the gem line does in fact install Rails automatically what program handles this execution?  Where would the install be located?

> rvm use ruby-2.1.1@myapp --ruby-version --create

Comment: If you put `gem rails` with a specific version in your Gemfile, running `bundle install` in console will install that version of the Rails gem. You do need to install Ruby separately, which should be done first along with installing Rubygems (the package manager).

Comment: Additionally, the `gem install` is handled by Rubygems, which you install after installing Ruby. The installation of gems can be different between computers, so to find out where Rails is installed (for example) you can run `gem which rails`.